# how to get json array and object

Tags: android

below is my code i want to parse json data in my code bur im not getting array "dish_nutrition":   its show error on line 6 The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)  please heelp me what do i do??
what is the correct way to parse this data???

```
"status":1,
"data":
"dish_nutrition":
{"1":
{"name":"Cholesterol and Diet",
"qty":"2"},
"2":
{"name":"Cholesterol and Diet",
"qty":"1"
}
}}



          JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

                    JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");




           final TableLayout table = (TableLayout)  findViewById(R.id.table2);
            for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {

     //line6 show rror The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not  
             applicable for the arguments (int)      
   line 6//   final View row =    createRow(school3.getJSONObject(j));
                table.addView(row);

            }







            public View createRow(JSONObject item) throws JSONException {
    View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.localTime)).setText(item
            .getString("name"));
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp)).setText(item

    .getString("qty"));

    return row;






                   <TableLayout
         android:id="@+id/table2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text23"
         android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
         android:paddingBottom="20dp"

         android:layout_marginRight="45dp"

      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:stretchColumns="*" >

     <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border7"
     >



    <TextView
        android:gravity="left"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:background="@drawable/border7"
         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Quantity" />
     <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Item"
        android:background="@drawable/border7"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>



     ///row.xml///////////



       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >


  <TextView

   android:id="@+id/apprentTemp"
     android:textColor="#000000"
      android:background="@drawable/border7"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:gravity="left"


   />
 <TextView

     android:id="@+id/localTime"
     android:textColor="#000000"
      android:background="@drawable/border7"
      android:gravity="center"


   />



     </TableRow>
```

Comment: please tell me "dish_nutrition":  is array or object???

Comment: i want to display data like this way http://imgur.com/mQd3cmA    i update my all xml code above

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an int to the method `getJSONObject()` at: createRow(school3.getJSONObject(j). j is an int.

school3 is an object not an array. You can get values by `school3.getJSONObject("1")`. Maybe you want to use an array instead of an object if that is possible? Now you can get the name value by doing: `school3.getJSONObject("1").getString("name")`;

Using an array it would look like:

```
"dish_nutrition":
[ {"name":"Cholesterol and Diet", "qty":"2"},
  {"name":"Cholesterol and Diet", "qty":"1"} ]
```

You can then get the array: `json2.getJSONArray("dish_nutrition");`
And loop over it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject jObject = school3.getJSONObject(j);
    String name = jObject.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: str is correct i debug at this line
JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");
school3  show all data when watch on debug mode

Comment: Ok. It's the school3.getJSONObject. I updates my answer. What are you trying to get here?

Comment: all json file data shows at this stage
                    JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");

how to get its inside data it is aray or object??

Comment: so what do i do? whats ur recomendation?

Comment: Are you in control of the JSON? If so, use an array for dish_nutrition

Comment: Well... if you look at my code you can see where I get the String. Use it there to put in a textview. I guess you are a little new to all of this. So why not follow a tutorial about this? http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: u just store name in string  where u store qty???? and how u display same like my screeen?

Comment: You can get qty: jObject.getString("qty"); But please follow a tutorial about this to learn about it. Same for the layout. Enough basic tutorials to follow on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you spend some time learning Jackson a High-performance JSON processor Java library. it is very simple to use yet extremely powerful